# How to view xaml markup View during development?

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

How to view xaml markup View during development?

Time-bound example: https://youtu.be/Ck0SHVWI89E?t=131

[image]

---

### Upadte-1

OS Name Microsoft Windows 10 Enterprise
Version 10.0.19043 Build 19043
Manufacturer System manufacturer
Model System Product Name
Type x64-based computer
System SKU To Be Filled By O.E.M.
Processor Pentium(R) Dual-Core CPU E5300 @ 2.60GHz, 2603 MHz, Cores: 2, Logical
Processors: 2
BIOS version of American Megatrends Inc. 0406, 10.06.2009
SMBIOS Version 2.5
Main board manufacturer ASUSTeK Computer INC.
Main board model P5QL/EPU
Version of the main board Rev X.0x
Hardware-dependent Level (HAL) Version = "10.0.19041.1151"
Installed RAM (6.00 GB)
The total amount of physical memory is 6.00 GB
Available physical memory 898 MB
Total virtual memory 13.9 GB
Available virtual memory 3.02 GB
Swap file size 7.91 GB

Name NVIDIA GeForce 6800 GS
PCI PNP Device ID\VEN_10DE&DEV_00C0&SUBSYS_00000000&REV_A2\4&39043ADE&0&0008
GeForce 6800 GS adapter type, NVIDIA-compatible
Description of the NVIDIA GeForce 6800 GS Adapter
Adapter RAM 256.00 MB (268,435,456 bytes)
Installed drivers nvd3dumx.dll
Driver version 9.18.13.908
INF file oem6.inf (section Section002)
Color planes are not available
Elements of the color table 4294967296
Resolution 1920 x 1080 x 60 Hz

Comment: There is no XAML preview.  You can use [Hot Reload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/hot-reload) to view changes in your UI as you adjust your XAML

Comment: @Jason **1.** How was the viewing done in the video tutorial?
**2.** Are there xaml viewers for Xamarin?
**3.** I have a weak computer. I can't run the android emulator. Is there anything you can think of to work around the problem with the emulator?

Comment: @Jason See **Update-1**

Comment: the tutorial is using Android AXML, not XAML

Comment: @Jason I can't run the Android emulator for debugging.
Is it because I have a weak computer?
See **Update-1**.
But I can run UWP for debugging.

Comment: I don't think you understand what Jason said. There is NO WAY to preview XAML. You can't do what you want with `Xamarin.Forms`. The tutorial you mention is using "AXML", which is native Android UI, via `Xamarin.Android`. Not cross-platform. That is a different topic; Not relevant to what you are trying to do.